# ews-javascript-api getAttachments throw Object doesn't support this action

Tags: ews-javascript-api

I'm using ews-js-api-browser to develop an outlook desktop add-in.
EwsJS namespace is currently imported with a `<script>` tag, like office-js library.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    EwsJS.ConfigureForOutlook()
    EwsJS.EwsLogging.DebugLogEnabled = false
}

const functionWhichNeedAttachment = () => {
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync((token) => {
    const exch = new EwsJS.ExchangeService(EwsJS.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016)
    exch.Credentials = new EwsJS.OAuthCredentials(token.value)
    exch.Url = new EwsJS.Uri(Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl)

    exch.GetAttachments(
      [Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments[0].id],
      1,
      null).then(res => console.log('res', res))

  })
})
}
```

I get this error :

> Object doesn't support this action ExchangeWebService.js (41867, 9)

It seems like ExchangeWebService is trying to assign a value to a forbidden keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services

there is only subset of EWS operations available using `mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` which is internally used by ews-javascript-api for Outlook/Mail app.

unfortunately `GetAttachments` is not available in mail apps.

Comment: If so, is there any way to get attachments from an outlook addin ?

Comment: If you are looking at some properties you can use native Outlook Add-In API, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox.item?view=office-js#attachments-arrayattachmentdetailsjavascriptapioutlook16officeattachmentdetails)

Comment: I've seen that, but I want to access the attachment content itself. But it appear that it's impossible with a JS add in. Thanks for your help !